# dynamically slice array of product data to display in ReactJs component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I'm building an ecommerce store with Reactjs where I need to display the products in home component dynamically. Now in the home component the products should follow some styling like for example 4 products in first row, 1 in second row, 3 in the next row etc. I'm calling all the product data array from the database as products and passing them in another component called `Products component` by mapping through the products array. But in doing so I'm using `slice()` method and hard coding how many and which products should pass in the in each rows. Is there a way instead of hardcoding number of products per row like `Array.slice(0,4)` I can achieve the same styling in a more dynamic way

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import Product from "./Product";
import { db } from "./firebase";

function Home() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("products").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setProducts(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, products: doc.data() }))
      );
    });

return (
    <div className="home">
        <div className="home__container">

          <div className="home__row">
                 {products.slice(0, 4).map(({ id, products }) => (      //Hard coding number of products
            <Product 
              key={id}
              title={products.title}
              price={products.price}
              image={products.image}
              rating={products.rating}
            />
          ))}
        </div>

          <div className="home__row">

              {products.slice(4).map(({ id, products }) => (            //Hard coding number of products
            <Product
              key={id}
              title={products.title}
              price={products.price}
              image={products.image}
              rating={products.rating}
            />
          ))}
        </div>

          <div className="home__row">
                {products.slice(5, 10).map(({ id, products }) => (      //Hard coding number of products
            <Product
              key={id}
              title={products.title}
              price={products.price}
              image={products.image}
              rating={products.rating}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can achieve the same thing with CSS. Set display: flex for parent div and flex: 0 25% for each product item:

```
<div style={{style: "display: flex"}}>
  {

    products.map((product, index)=>{
      <div style={{flex: "0 25%"}}>
        <Product 
              key={id}
              title={product.title}
              price={product.price}
              image={product.image}
              rating={product.rating}
            />
      </div>  
    })
  }
</div>
```

But in case you still prefer your current approach then I can suggest this solution:

```
{
  const productWithRows = products.reduce((memo, product, index)=>{
    memo[Math.floor(index/4] = product;
    return memo;
  },[])

  productWithRows.map((productsPerRow, index)=> {
    <div className="home__row">   
      {productsPerRow.map((product)=>{

        <Product 
          key={id}
          title={product.title}
          price={product.price}
          image={product.image}
          rating={product.rating}
        />
      })}
  </div>
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
follow some styling like for example 4 products in first row, 1 in second row, 3 in the next row etc.
```

This makes you do hard-coding, if you want to avoid this, you should pass those numbers(rules) via props or fetch from database.